# what's the meaning of "active for"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

"He's very active for a man approaching 80".

This sentence has been taken from Cambridge Dictionary. To know the meaning of "approach" I searched in this dictionary and I found this sentence. Who is active? The man whose age is near to 80? Or other person who want to help the old person?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A special use of the preposition *'for'!*

[OALD entry #12:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/for_1?q=for)

> *for*: considering **what can be expected from somebody/something**

Do you get it now?

When we are nearing 80, our *activeness* is likely to be reduced. But, he's quite active that you don't expect it at that age.